# How to mock the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nunit

I have a method in a controller that check's the user's role to see which page the user should be redirected.
I am trying to do unit testing for the following code

```
public class HomeController: Controller {

    //...

    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrators")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/administrator");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/user");
        }
    }

    //...other actions
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I tried to do unit testing but it is throwing an error for controllerContextMock.Setup( x => x.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals("administrator")))).Returns(true);

Comment: @Fedrick Please [edit] your question and add the piece of code that is actually giving you problems as well as details about the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Xerillio I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mock setup is incorrect; you actually cannot mock members of concrete classes (unless they're virtual). But thankfully that's no big deal here, because you don't need to use a mock. Generally speaking the following is a working way of dealing with `HttpContext` testing:

```csharp
    [Test]
    public async Task HomeReturnsNotNull()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();
        var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
            {
                User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrators") }))
            }
        };
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;

        ActionResult index = (ActionResult)controller.Home();

        Assert.IsNotNull(index);
    }
```

But it's often more comfortable to rely on some abstractions of your own, instead of calling `HttpContext` members directly.

Took the liberty to change `'admin'` to `'Administrators'`, because I noticed a discrepancy between the value in the test and the value in the controller action.

This way the `IsInRole()` check in the controller action should execute properly, which should be useful in the other tests (since in this one it seems you're just checking against null).